# Нужно ли выполнять delete для полученых из вне указателей

Tags: c++

Демонстрационный код:

```
MyType getDataFromDB()
{
    Driver *driver;
    Connection *con;
    Statement *stmt;
    ResultSet *res;

    /* Create a connection */
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "login", "pass");
    /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
    con->setSchema("schema");
    stmt = con->createStatement();
    MyType resultAnythngAndAnother;

    // Первый запрос
    res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT anything");

    while (res->next())
    {
        // перебор данных с запроса "SELECT anything"
    }

    delete res; // <----- Вопрос #1: Нужно ли делать delete res перед новым использованием переменной res?

    // Другой запрос
    res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT another");

    while (res->next())
    {
        // перебор данных с запроса "SELECT another"
    }

    delete res; // <----- Вопрос #2: Достаточно ли сделать delete res только тут?

    return resultAnythngAndAnother;
}
```

- Вопрос #1: Нужно ли делать `delete res` перед новым использованием
  переменной `res`?
- Вопрос #2: Достаточно ли сделать `delete res` только    после
  последнего вызова (когда она уже не будет больше использоваться)?

Comment: Вопросы лучше писать отдельно от кода или дублировать их в коде.  Иначе суть топика будет сложна для восприятия.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правило состоит в том, что простого правила «делайте так и не думайте» нет.

У каждого указателя в вашей программе есть *владелец* — тот, кто ответственен за время жизни объекта. Именно этот владелец должен удалять объект, и обязан знать, когда объект должен быть удалён.

Если вы получаете указатель из какой-либо функции, в документации **обязано** быть написано, передаётся ли владение вам (и значит, вы теперь ответственный за удаление объекта), или оно остаётся за прежним владельцем (и значит, вы не имеете права удалять объект). Если такой информации в документации нет, выясните это у разработчика. Если разработчик недоступен, попробуйте воспользоваться здравым смыслом.

Если вы сами разрабатываете функцию, которая возвращает указатель, **вы** должны решить, передаёте вы владение объектом вместе с указателем или нет, и отобразить этот факт в документации.

---

Для вашего случая с точки зрения здравого смысла каждый `stmt->executeQuery` выделяет собственную память, которая не принадлежит вам, т. к. она переиспользуется при каждом `next()`. Скорее всего, однако, вы должны тем или иным образом закрыть `Connection`, иначе внешний код не будет знать, когда ему можно освободить эту память.

Но вообще-то, загляните лучше в документацию. Например, вот эти страницы [[1]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-connecting.html), [[2]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-results.html) сообщают:

> Make sure that you free `con`, the `sql::Connection` object, as soon as you do not need it any more. But do not explicitly free `driver`, the connector object.

> You must free the `sql::Statement`, `sql::Connection`, and `sql::ResultSet` objects explicitly using `delete`.

То есть, вам передаётся владение (и ответственность за удаление) `con`, `stmt`, `res`, но не `driver`.

А значит, вы обязаны удалить объект по указателю `res` перед тем, как вы присвоите *переменной* `res` новое значение (и потеряете указатель на объект, за который вы ответственны).

Answer (score 3):

У вас переменная объявлена как указатель `ResultSet *res;`. Указатель - это просто несколько байт, куда помещается адрес некоей выделенной области памяти. Вы выполняете `executeQuery`, он возвращает адрес созданного им объекта. Вы этот адрес просто кладете в свой указатель. Следующий `executeQuery` просто создает новый объект и возвращает адрес другой выделенной области памяти. Если вы его просто присвоите переменной `res` то затрете тот адрес, который там лежит, а область памяти, на которую он указывал, так и останется занятой. Следовательно вам *необходимо* выполнять `delete res` после каждого использования.

И когда ваша функция завершится потеряются все ее переменные, следовательно перед завершением она по хорошему должна не забыть удалить еще stmt, con и driver. Хотя конечно коннекты к базе будут у вас наверняка в другом месте и вам не потребуется их постоянно создавать и удалять. А вот `stmt` точно забывать не стоит, он у вас скорее всего будет новый при каждом вызове функции.

Comment: `driver` не нужно удалять, если верить документации

Comment: @VladD вот не подумал бы никогда, что разработчики не завершенный код предоставлять могут

Comment: @perfect: Разработчики — такие же люди. :(

Answer (score 2):

По хорошему тону, ответы на вопросы 1 и 2 - нет и нет.

Причины:

- Вы не имеете права удалять память выделенную не Вами - строка `res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT anything");` подразумивает, что выделение происходит в stmt - так и удалить её должна она же!
  Взависимости от доступа к методу `executeQuery` можно: вернуть `std::unique_ptr<ReturnType>` или записывать сразу в такой указатель `res.reset( stmt->execute() )` при условии, что res уже умный указатель.
- Если Ваш код имеет место фразе "*главное не забыть сделать это*" - поверьте вы забудете это: не сегодня, так через месяц. Я уже молчу про сопровождающего код программиста, который понятия не имеет, что он "должен" и кому ).

Рекомендации:

1. почитайте про ***C++ RAII***
2. Ознакомьтесь с ссылкой https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-ptr

Comment: А ничего, что в документации на MySQL в примерах явно показано, что объект должен удалять вызывающий ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-results.html

Comment: @Mike будьте внимательные при чтении поста, а именно : `или записывать сразу в такой указатель res.reset( stmt->execute() ) при условии, что res уже умный указатель`. Если библиотека так устроена, то не проблема - записали в умный указатель и не видим `delete` в коде без `new`.

Comment: @rikimaru2013: «Нету `delete`» и «не видим `delete`» — разные вещи. `unique_ptr` и есть «спрятанный» `delete`. (Что по идее хорошо, т. к. ранние возвраты и исключения.)

Comment: @VladD а я как написал?) Не пойму я вас - зачем был этот комментарий, но догодываюсь ... ))))

Comment: @rikimaru2013: Вы написали в комментарии «не видим delete в коде без new». Суть основного вопроса не в том, должен ли быть delete _видимым_, а в том, должен ли он быть _по сути_. Понимаете?

Comment: @rikimaru2013: Поэтому ваш ответ «нет» в первой строчке неверен. То, как синтаксически оформляется `delete` — явным вызовом или через смарт-пойнтер — вопрос второстепенный.

Answer (score 1):

Оператор `delete` возвращает память, которая выделена для объекта обратно в кучу, чтобы не было утечек или ошибок.Тем более, Вы работаете с БД.

А, вообще есть "золотое правило работы с любыми ресурсами":

- Заняли ресурс (создали объект);
- Использовали ресурс;
- Освободили ресурс.

И так при каждом использовании.

Comment: От сюда следует, что на Вопрос #1 ответ - "Да"?

Comment: ИМХО, можно отсюда можно сделать выводы для обоих вопросов. Как говорится, "от греха подальше" освобождать ресурсы сразу же после использования. А, вообще, если на чистоту, код в топике не оптимизирован. Переменная `res` используется 2 раза совершенно аналогичным образом. Отличаются только выполняемые запросы. Если Вы выделите алгоритм работы с `res`,например, в отдельную функцию, то вопрос#2 отпадёт сам собой.

Comment: На счёт чистоты кода - это просто демо для вопроса с delete. В настоящем коде, конечно же, не так :)

Comment: Тогда, простите, какой смысл выкладывать такой код? Некорректно иллюстрируя вопрос в примере кода Вы только запутаете отвечающих и сами потом запутаетесь. В прочем, Вам виднее..

Answer (score 1):

В С++ есть фишка связанная с вашим вопросом. А то есть после удаления указателя его можно обнулить и последующее удаление не приведет к ошибке, например:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int * i; // создали указатель

    i = new int; // распеределили память для переменной

    delete i; // удалили память, теперь i это просто указатель который ни начто не указывает

    // delete i; - если мы еще раз вызовем удаление то получим ошибку, потому что удалять уже нечего и в этом указателе находится мусорный адресс который указывает ни на что

    i = 0; // теперь указатель указывает на первый блок памяти

    delete i; // теперь это стало безопасным благодоря обнулению указателя

    return 0;
}
```

а насчет распределения и удалении памяти то они желательно должны находится в одной зоне видимости чтоб код был простым и не содержал ошибок. но это скорее совет чем инструкция к действию.